# In Dynamically generated Dropdown when im selecting an option respective function is not called

Tags: jquery

I'm generating a button in every chart dynamically.
LIKE THIS :

```
"<a id='gridBtn_"+i+"' href='javascript:;'  class='icon-table'  onclick='showGridIcons(this)'></a>"
```

On clicking that button in any chart im generating a dropdown dynamically

LIKE THIS :

```
"<div id='grid-icons_"+i+"' style='position:absolute;z-index:1;display:none;' >"+
    "<select  id='gridType' onchange='javascript:alert('hello');'>"+
     "<option  value='Grid_"+i+"'>Grid</option>"+
    "<option   value='Pivot_"+i+"'>Pivot</option>"+
    "</select></div>"

function  showGridIcons(gridBtn) {
    var btnId = gridBtn.id;
    i = parseInt(btnId.split("_")[1]);

    $('#grid-icons_'+i).slideToggle(1000);
}
```

Now my question is when im selecting option from that dropdown respective function is not called

LIKE THIS:

```
$('#gridType').on('change', function(){

    try{
        if(type==='Grid'){
            alert("GRID"):
        }
        else{
        alert("PIVOT"):
}

    }
    catch(err){
        alert(err);
    }
}

);
```

Comment: You need to bind your `.on()` function elsewhere because `#gridType` is dynamically added.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're dealing with dynamically generated elements, you need to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)'s delegated syntax. Change:

```
$('#gridType').on('change', function(){
```

to:

```
$(document).on('change', '#gridType' ,function(){
```

From the docs:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

Ideally you want to use an element closer to the target element than `document` which is a worst case scenario.

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document
>   tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must
>   compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every
>   element in the path from the event target up to the top of the
>   document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document
>   location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive
>   use of document or document.body for delegated events on large
>   documents.

Comment: No need to shout. What errors are you getting? Can you create a jsFiddle.net example showing the problem?